# Getting error while implementing web-view in flutter applications

Tags: android, flutter, webview, dependencies

I am building a flutter app that has a web-view. I have updated the minsdkversion to 20. and added the android permission to use the internet but still getting the errror.[click here to view error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbJ3i.png)

**DART**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      home: WebViewApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class WebViewApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const WebViewApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<WebViewApp> createState() => _WebViewAppState();
}

class _WebViewAppState extends State<WebViewApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flutter WebView'),
      ),
      body: const WebView(
        initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev',
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using android phone? Your error message indicates TargetPlatform.windows

Comment: Okay. I will try to run it on Android. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) that support platform Android and iOS, but you trying to run on web, that's why this error occurs.

Thanks,

Happy Codding!

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code into my machine it works fine on android devices. I hope you are running your app on an android or ios device because `flutter_webview: any` version supports only Android and ios devices as per the official doc.
[image: See this image]